# Load external img as background of div after getting img via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a chrome app and i would like to load external img as background-image of `<div>` element.

I found the following article : https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#cross-origin

I wuild the following function :

```
this.loadImgFromUrl = function loadImgFromUrl(url, el) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function(e) {
              // How to load my img as url as background ?
              //$("#img_me_area").css('background-image', 'url("' + photoUrl + '")');
            };

            xhr.send();
        } ;
```

I don't know how to set the img as the background of my div.

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about Chrome Apps, but if you cannot access the imge directly by the URL (for w/e reason) you might want to convert it to Base64 once loaded, and then set the Base64 encoded string as background image?

You can read about Base64 images in CSS [over here](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

Otherwise, it is just as simple as:

```
("#img_me_area").css('background-image', 'url("' + url+ '")');
```